# how to assign static internal IP addresses to google cloud stateful managed instance group manager using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

I am creating a stateful managed instance group manager to create three VMs in three different zones and attaching the disk corresponding to zone. Here is the terraform code

```
locals {
  node_zone_mapping    = {"git-1" = "us-central1-a", "git-2" = "us-central1-b"}
}
// Create instance group manager for gitaly nodes
resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "git-server-mig" {
  description = "Terraform test instance group manager"
  name        = "exp-manage-git-mig"

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.git-server.self_link
  }

    update_policy {
     type                         = "OPPORTUNISTIC"
     instance_redistribution_type = "NONE"
     minimal_action               = "REPLACE"
     max_unavailable_fixed        = 2

  }
  base_instance_name = "exp-git-server"
  region                = "us-central1"
  target_size        = 2
  distribution_policy_zones = ["us-central1-a", "us-central1-b"]

}

// define state config for MIG
resource "google_compute_region_per_instance_config" "preserve_gitaly_disk" {
  for_each = local.node_zone_mapping
  region = "us-central1"
  region_instance_group_manager = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.git-server-mig.name
  name = format("exp-%s-%s", each.key, local.short_ver)
  preserved_state {
    disk {
      device_name = format("exp-disk-%s-%s", each.key, local.short_ver)
      source      = google_compute_disk.git-disk[each.key].self_link
      mode        = "READ_WRITE"
    }
  }
}
```

One of the requirement is to assign static ip address to each vm based on zone.
I looked at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_per_instance_config . It has the facility for disk assignment but not IP assignment. Basically I am trying to achieve the same as described in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/configuring-stateful-ip-addresses-in-migs#configuring_static_ip_addresses_on_vm_creation_in_a_mig in terraform way.

Comment: Why do you need IP? The principle of managed instance group is a scalability up and down, and, by design you can predefined the used IPs. Only the range

Comment: Basically, my requirement is to have 3 VMs with predefined naming like vm-0, vm-1 and vm-2, so that i can attach correct disk as per name + health check facility/restart/replace the nodes. individual VMs can't have health check. that's why I chose stateful MIG. additionally, there is another service which needs ip address of these VMs. I hope, I am able to explain to use-case. i can create 3 static ips using google_compute_address tf resource. It is just a matter of assigning them which I am not able to find.